# I cant figure out what is wrong with my code. i keep getting errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
e1 = input("Enter Ingredient 1: ")
e1o = input("How Many Ounces Of " + e1 + ':')
e2 = input("Enter Ingredient 2: ")
e2o = input("How Many Ounces of " + e2 + ':')
e3 = input("Enter Ingredient 3: ")
e3o = input("How many ounces of " + e3 + ':')
serve = input('How Many Servings?: ')

print('Total ounces of ' + e1 + ': ' + str(serve * e1o))
print('Total ounces of ' + e2 + ': ' + str(serve * e20))
print('Total ounces of ' + e3 + ': ' + str(serve * e3o))
```

The errors I'm getting are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    print('Total ounces of ' + e1 + ': ' + int(str(serve * e1o)))
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: The post title should describe your question or problem well enough so that readers get the gist of what it's about ("Problem with Java function" is not very descriptive). See: [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Comment: `serve * e20` might be a typo. Replace `e20` with `e2o`

Comment: ok p. James k. Polk fixed it it was such a stupid error i had. Sorry guys!!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `input()` method in python to take input from the user, it will take all input as a string. You then try to multiple 2 string together, make sure you cast the strings to numbers before applying the math operator to them like below:

```
print('Total ounces of ' + e1 + ': ' + str(int(serve) * int(e1o)))
print('Total ounces of ' + e2 + ': ' + str(int(serve) * int(e2o)))
print('Total ounces of ' + e3 + ': ' + str(int(serve) * int(e3o)))
```